# [SymmetricDS]: DBCompare tool for source table without primary key

Tags: symmetricds

I'm having source and target databases of different structure. My source tables don't have PK, target tables have.
During sync, it will assume all source column as PK if I don't specify anything. So my current settings for the tables to sync correctly is I have transformation on those column PK=0 during LOAD.

When I run dbcompare command, some tables failed to run comparison because it complains source table doesn't have PK.

Is this a known error or can it be resolved ?

Comment: Currently DBCompare requires primary keys at the source database.   The tool should probably be enhanced to take into account either sym_trigger.sync_key_names or column transforms.

If you make the target database the source database for comparison purposes it might work although the results might be a bit backwards ...

Comment: I tried reverse the source and target but no comparison at all. Are there settings I need to configure to allow this ? It is ok because I only want to know the differences.